# awk - parse text having same character in fields as delimiter

Tags: regex, bash, awk, capture-group

Consider this source:

```
field1;field2;"data;data field3";field4;"data;data field5";field6
field1;"data;data field2";field3;field4;field5;"data;data field6"
```

As you can see, the field delimiter is being used inside certain fields, enclosed between `"`. I cannot directly parse with `awk` because there is no way of avoiding unwanted splitting, at least I haven't found a way. Moreover, those special fields have a variable position within a line and they can occur once, twice, 4 times etc.

I thought of a solution involving a pre-parsing step, where I replace the `;` in those fields with a code of some sort. The problem is that `sed` / `awk` perform greedy `REGEX` match. So in the above example, I can only replace `;` within the last field enclosed in quotes in each line.

How can I match each instance of quotes and replace the specific `;` within them? I do not want to use `perl` or `python` etc.

Comment: what is it that you want to do once you've separated the fields? and why do you not want to use `perl`? it is just another tool like `awk` that can be used on command line... with `GNU awk` you can use https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html#Splitting-By-Content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `gnu awk` you can use special `FPAT` variable to have a regex for your fields.

You can use this command to replace all `;` by `|` inside the double quotes:

```
awk -v OFS=';' -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^;]*' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) gsub(/;/, "|", $i)} 1' file

field1;field2;"data|data field3";field4;"data|data field5";field6
field1;"data|data field2";field3;field4;field5;"data|data field6"
```

Comment: I had no idea about `FPAT` as a way to define fields by what they are instead of what they are not, like the normally used `-F`. This is awesome, I can actually parse my source directly using this method. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to `FPAT` you can set the `awk` `FS` to be double quotes and then swap out your semicolon delimiter for every other field:

```
awk -F"\"" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){ if(i%2==0) gsub(/;/, "|", $i)}} {print $0}' yourfile
```

Here awk is:

1. Splitting the record by double quote (`-F"\""`)
2. Looping through each field that it finds (`{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)`)
3. Testing the field ordinal's mod 2 if it's 0 (`if(i%2==0)`)
4. If it's even then it swaps out the semicolons with pipes (`gsub(/;/, "|", $i)`)
5. Prints out the transformed record (`{print $0}`)